# Monotonicity of finite Moment generating functions

Tags: probability

Suppose that MX(s) < ∞ for some s > 0. Show that MX(t) < ∞ for all t ∈ [0, s]. 
Similarly, suppose that MX(s) < ∞ for some s < 0. Show that MX(t) < ∞ for all t ∈ [s, 0].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$tX=\frac t s (sX)+(1-\frac t s) 0$. Exponential function is convex, so this gives $e^{tX} \leq \frac t s e^{sX}+(1-\frac t s) e^{0}$. Hence $Ee^{tX} \leq \frac t s Ee^{sX}+(1-\frac t s) <\infty $. The second result is proved in a similar fashion. You can also prove it by changing $X$ to $-X$ in the first result.